# Is there a way to avoid this warning from clang++ (fuchsia-default-arguments) while using a vector float?

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17, clang++

Consider this program:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      fstream file;
      int line_count = 0;
      int months;
      string name_file;

      std::cout << "Please input the file name for your report file: "; 
      std::cin >> name_file;

      if (name_file != "load_report.txt")
      {
        std::cout << "Invalid report file!\n";
        exit(1);
      }

      std::cout << "Please provide the number of months to consolidate: ";
      std::cin >> months;

      if (months <= 0)
      {
        std::cout << "You need to have at least one month in order to"
                  << " consolidate your sales.\n";
        exit(1); 
      }

      std::cout << "\n";

      file.open(name_file, ios::in);

      if (file.is_open())
      {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
          line_count++;

        }
      }

      else
      {
        std::cout << "Could not open file!\n";
        exit(1);
      }

      file.close();

      file.open(name_file, ios::in);

      vector<float> a(line_count);
      int k = 0;

      if (file.is_open())
      {
        for (auto & val : a)
        {
          file >> val;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout << "Could not open file!\n";
        exit(1);
      }

      file.close();

      int loops = line_count / months;

      for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
      {
        float sum = 0;
        std::cout << "Month ";
        for (int j = 0; j < months; ++j)
        {
          std::cout << i * months + j + 1 << " ";
          sum += a[i * months + j];
        }
        std::cout << "sales: $" << sum << "\n";
      }

      return 0;
   }
```

Running `make stylecheck` returns the following:

```
    16369 warnings generated.

    /home/bl71/bl71/prob-02/prob-02-main.cpp:64:17: warning: calling a function that uses a default
    argument is disallowed [fuchsia-default-arguments-calls]
       vector<float> a(line_count);
                     ^
    /../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:507:29: note: default
    parameter was declared here
       vector(size_type __n, const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
                             ^
```

Is there an argument that can be passed through to make this warning go away? This is a program I am trying to write that loads a monthly report from a report file and displays the consolidated sales for a given range of months. In my directory, a `load_report.txt` file was manually created and I use this program to read its contents of that file using `fstream`. `make stylecheck` checks for internal documentation guidelines.

Comment: The `std::vector<float>` constructor you are using accepts a second argument with type `std::allocator<float>` (named in `std::vector` with a typedef `allocator_type`) and default value `std::allocator<float>()`. One option is to pass a value `std::allocator<float>()` as the second argument, which is a pain as a lot of usage of `std::vector` would need similar changes. IMHO, though, clang-tidy is being too picky, as few users of `std::vector` need to worry about explicitly passing allocators since the default is (well) a decent default - so it may be worth disabling that warning.

Comment: Looks like your stylecheck script needs to be edited/improved.

Comment: @Peter Actually it is tested using clang++ -std=c++17, not clang-tidy.

Comment: @Benson - whatever.   My comment was made when your subject line said it was clang-tidy giving the warning, and before you edited to change that.  Whatever checker you're using, it is being too picky in this case.

Comment: @Peter It was my bad. So if use ```allocator<float>```, does that mean I need to make more changes to my program?

Comment: What I means is that, if you define lots of vectors, almost every definition will need a similar modification.   For a small code sample that is fine, but it is rare that a substantial program will be limited to only defining one or two vectors.   And, incidentally, the default allocator type depends on the element type of the vector - a `std::vector<float>` uses a `std::allocator<float>` by default.   A `std::vector<SomeOtherType>` will use a `std::allocator<SomeOtherType>` by default, not a `std::allocator<float>`.